# Is there a way to add Circular positioning in constraint layout v1.1.0 using Layout Editor not XML?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I was reading about the new version of constraint layout and noticed this amazing Circular constraint feature. I mostly use the editor to add constraints add barriers, groups and so on, but I couldn't find the circular constraint in the editor. Is it just an XML feature so far(It would be a bit annoying for me to go to the XML for just adding/editing this feature)? Or did I miss it?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but in case anyone else is looking for how to use this programmatically.

You can create a `ConstraintSet` for your child views, and use it's `constrainCircle` method to set the view to center around, radius, and angle.